# Is Hidden QWidget object receives signals

Tags: qt, qt4, widget, signals, qwidget

Simple Query:

If GUI widget window is hidden does it receives signals from other objects?
In our Qt application we have seen this issue/behaviour.

However, when window is shown it receives and process all the signals that it receives.

Comment: "have seen this issue" - Are you implying that you're not receiving them when a window is hidden?

Comment: Yes, I am seeing odd behaviour that window is hidden it is unable to process the pending signals.

Comment: As mentioned in the two answers, signals continue to be processed, unless you disconnect them. Can you provide more detail about what connections you're making and what should be happening when minimized, preferably including samples of code?

Answer (score 3):

Every QObject (and hense every QWidget) receives signals until it's destroyed or the signal is disconnected. Visibility doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't disconnect signals while hiding the QWidget they're received and processed.

Comment: if you need to use the same signals again, maybe `blockSignals(bool)` would be the best choice. but you are right, disconnected signals is a good way